# How to use Ethereum precompile bn256Pairing to check equality on symmetric groups?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, cryptography, pairings

The address *0x8* contains [*bn256Pairing*](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-197.md) pre-compiled contract on Byzantium release. I have the following questions :

1. If I have *G_1 = G_2*, i.e., a symmetric pairing, is it possible to check *e(a_1, b_1) ?= e(a_2, b_2)* ? If yes, how do I pass the arguments because the specification uses a [representation](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-197.md#encoding) like *ai+b*.
2. What is the exact encoding of the elements to be used? Is there a sample code or test case reference available? I'm trying to use assembly calls inside Solidity contracts.

In case it is not possible to use the pre-compiled contracts, can I edit the geth source code and test it on a private network? If yes, where can I add the relevant functions inside the source?

Comment: The pairing check only works over the particular groups defined by y^2=x^3+3 on the fields F_p, F_p^2

Comment: In particular, the pairing is type-3, i.e. not symmetric

Comment: Thanks. If I want to write a function into geth source and test on a private network, any pointer as to how to do that?

Comment: This commit added a bunch, it might help you out https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/9facf6423dbd38ebd7fbd9069cbcb98b0fd243c2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To whoever stumbled upon this question looking for a solution:

I edited `core/vm/contracts.go` to add relevant pre-compiled contracts. I used [PBC package](https://godoc.org/github.com/Nik-U/pbc) to implement the symmetric bilinear pairing. The structure of function same as other pre-compiled contract functions defined in that file.

Works well in a private network.